One data set drawn from multiple distributions
I have a problem figuring out how to fit a dataset that, at least visually, has been pulled from multiple distributions.
My attempt was to use GaussianMixture, but the result doesn't look convincing. I am not good at statistics and not trying to argue that it is incorrect, but it is not something that I have expected. The code is here:
import numpy as np
from pylab import *
from sklearn.mixture import GaussianMixture
from pylab import concatenate, normal
import pandas as ps

from scipy.stats import norm

df = ps.read_csv('Book6.csv')
multimodal_dist = df.E.to_numpy()

weights = np.ones_like(multimodal_dist)/float(len(multimodal_dist))
y, x, _=hist(multimodal_dist, bins=np.arange(df['E'].min(), df['E'].max()+1)-0.5, alpha=.5, weights=weights, label='data')

components = 2

gm = GaussianMixture(n_components=components)
gm.fit(multimodal_dist.reshape(-1, 1))

means = gm.means_
standard_deviations = gm.covariances_**0.5 
weights = gm.weights_ 

new_X = np.linspace(min(multimodal_dist), max(multimodal_dist), 100)

for mean, std, weight in zip(means, standard_deviations, weights):
    print(weight,mean, std)
    pdf = 2*weight * norm.pdf(new_X, mean, std)
    plt.plot(new_X.reshape(-1, 1), pdf.reshape(-1, 1), alpha=0.8)


pdf_full = np.zeros(len(new_X))
for i in range(components):
    pdf_full = pdf_full + weights[i] * norm.pdf(new_X, means[i], standard_deviations[i])

plt.plot(new_X.reshape(100,1), 2*pdf_full.reshape(-1, 1))

plt.show()

The plot that I produced from GaussianMixture fit coefficients is

The overall curve does look right, but the underlying distributions are not what I expected.
The plot that I expect has been manually fitted and is not statistically backed up, but I thought, it should be something like this:

Are my expectations just wrong or I am not using good methods, or misusing them? For one, my normalization has been done manually in both cases. I don't understand how to normalize my fits to match the distribution.
Data is here.


With these data you should look at the empirical cdf and compare the cdf of the mixture. You should see that your initial fit will be pretty good. 2. One issue with your expectation of what you should see is that you seem to be focused on fitting a component to the peaks but ignoring the effect of the other component. 3. One possible tool to aid intuition here may be fitting a kernel density estimate (with a smallish bandwidth), and seeing what that looks like. 4. It might help to say more about what the data are and what this continuous mixture approximation might be used to do.



In your title, presumably you mean 'drawn from' rather than 'drown from'. If so could you please edit to correct that, so that title-related searches work more effectively? On the other hand, if you do mean 'drown' could you consider explaining (in your question) the sense in which it applies here?  6. These points are pretty general but some will help when looking at applying @jginestet's insightful response.


What does your second plot mean??  In the first plot., the total heights of the orange and green components equal the red curve.  Totaling your orange and green curves in the second plot would result in a curve lying far above any of the bars in the plot, obviously incorrect.

Your data is discrete, and it looks to me as a mixture of 2 (or more?) discrete distributions, but with different "resolution" (i.e. different steps between possible discrete values). So when they coincide, you have large spikes (because both contribute), and otherwise, you really only have 1 distribution for that bin. If you look at an individual value plot (and zoom on the Y axis), you can clearly see this phenomenon (values increment by 2, and every other value has a lot more datapoints).



One distribution has a resolution of 2, and the other of 4 (or some multiple of 2). I would guess a resolution of 4, based on what happens at the extremes. See below, where data increments by 4:


So gaussians may approximate each discrete, but not that mixture very well (because for half the values, there is in fact no mixture). But if you took only the data points of the form $(-583+n.4)$ (-583 being the minima), there you will have a mixture; and all the other data points are only "the other distribution" (the one where discrete resolution=2). That will let you find exactly 1 of the 2 distributions. Then, based on the "modulo 4" values, you should be able to estimate the mixture ratio.
Now the scenario may be even more complex (more that 2 distributions??). That is possible, and harder to sort. Hopefully this helps.

Thanks a lot for your insightful answer! I did not notice that.

Where do you get your expected manual fit from?
It looks to me like you may just be eyeballing the graph and noticing that some of the local peaks look taller than others.  However, those local peaks are almost certainly just discretization (i.e. rounding) artifacts, and the fact that some of them are taller than others is likely simply because the data has been rounded, rescaled (by a factor less than 1 in absolute value) and rounded again (possibly several times with different scale factors).
This scaling and re-rounding has caused some bins of rounded values to end up with more samples than other nearby bins, simply because samples from more original bins happened end up in that bin after scaling and re-discretization.
One place where I've often seen plots like yours is in color histograms of digital photographs that have had their colors adjusted in post-processing.  Since the color of each pixel in a digital photo is stored as a discrete value (often three integers between 0 and 255 inclusive, one each for the red, green and blue components of the color), any scaling of these color values (e.g. to adjust the overall brightness or contrast of the image) results in these kinds of re-discretization artifacts.

In particular, just looking at the plot of your dataset, I feel like a perfectly plausible explanation of its origin would be that:

the distribution of your underlying source data is approximately Gaussian with mean near -300 and standard deviation around ±100;
this data has been rounded to nearest integer after sampling;
the rounded data has then been scaled down a factor of around 0.8, rounded again, and then scaled back up by a factor of 1.25 and rounded once more.

In particular, step 3 (or something like it) has merged about 20% of your sample bins into another adjacent bin, leaving your final dataset with a distinctive "comb-like" shape where some (more or less regularly spaced) bins have more values than other nearby bins, while other bins near them have none (because their values have been merged into another bin).
Of course, it's also possible that the original distribution underlying your data is not just a simple Gaussian, and indeed might be better modelled by a mixture of Gaussians.  But even if so, I'd expect it to look more like the fit suggested by GaussianMixture than what you've sketched by hand.

Thank you! This is a very useful response, though my data has not been explicitly rescaled. Nevertheless, very insightful! Thank you!
